# Initialize views of activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, view

Is it necessary to initialize all the `views` of `activity` in `onCreate()` only. Can you tell me best initializations of `views` of `activity`.

Thanks

Comment: It is recommended, but not necessary. Just make sure you initialize View before manipulating it

Answer (score 0):

**OnCreate()** : This method is called once when `activity` is to be created. That is why all the `gobal` and `static` content should go there. Example - This may include your `shared preferences`, `databases` initialisations.

**OnStart()** : This method is called when you see your `activity` over screen. It is foreground method. `OnStart()` ends with `OnStop()`. Example : Let us assume `A` and `B` `activity`, `A activity` has been created and currently in `onStart()` method is being called. When one switches to `B activity` then A's `OnStop()` method will be called and `B activity` will be created. Thus `OnStart()` and `OnStop()` methods are called when you switches onto `activities`.

So according to your question initialisation is done once so it should be done in `OnCreate()` method if it is done in `OnStart()` then initialisation will takes place every time when you switch between `activities`.

Source : Difference between `onCreate()` and `onStart()`?

Please take a look over here this will clear your all faults regarding life cycle [Activity | Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to initialize any view if you do not modify it.
2. you can initialize in any Activity lifecycle as your wish(before accessing).
3. But is is said as best practice to initialize it in onCreate().

Why:

1. if you see the lifecycle OnCreate is called when you app page is not shown. Like onStart called when app is partially visible & onResume is called when it is fully visible. So, mostly we want everything ready before seeing it. So that is one reason.
2. Another is findViewById is bit more expensive. So, we don't want to see that when app is visible.
3. OnStart & onResume may call multiple time when you go another page. So, it's preferable to initialize everything only once , than multiple time.

So, choice is yours now.